# Register all object creation events in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Consider sample `XML` document that is unmarshalling into object structure in `java` using `JAXB`, e.g.:

```
Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();
RootElement object = um.unmarshal(inputStream);
```

For some purposes I want to be able handling events of every new object of this structure creation. Inside that handlers I'd like to have references to these newly created objects. I wonder: **is it possible somehow in `JAXB`?**

More specifically, if my structure is something like this:

```
public class RootElement { 
      ChildElementType1 child1;
      ChildElementType2 child2;
      ...
}
```

So, I want to handle events of creation objects of all these types (`RootElement`, `ChildElementType`,...).

These handlers must be something *external*, so I don't want to place them inside default constructors of my objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, using `Listener` interface:

```
            um.setListener(new Unmarshaller.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void afterUnmarshal(Object target, Object parent) {
                    // handle what you want
                }
            });
```